# Why does a sonar or radar's frequency correlate with its resolution?

Tags: frequency, radar

A sonar's (or radar's) frequency determines its limit on the smallest size that it can detect and its resolution.
I've heard that it's due to aliasing, if so, please explain the reason behind it a little more.

EDIT: My own understading:
Lower frequencies don't reflect well off small objects, thus the reflected wave has a smaller amplitude and this increases the inaccuracy, but this is a practical rather than a physical limit as  devices with more precision can also detect smaller amplitudes better. Is this correct?

Comment: Too often overlooked in introductory instruction is the correspondence between this fact of wave-optics and the Heisenberg uncertainty principle of quantum mechanics (which after all relies on exactly the same math).

Answer (score 3):

I’ll confine my answer to pulsed radars.  Longer wavelengths reflect just fine from large targets, unless the targets have been specially shaped to minimize back-scatter by diverting reflections, as in the design of stealthy aircraft.

The range resolution is roughly $c/2B$, where *B* denotes signal bandwidth, which is limited in practice to roughly 10% of the frequency.  The cross-range angular resolution is roughly $\lambda /d$, where *d* denotes the diameter of the antenna.

(Remember that the terminology of resolution is topsy-turvy.  A *small* value for resolution is called *high* resolution.  More is less.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case where you use a pencil to draw a coastline. The finest detail of the coastline that you can put down would be the size of the pencils tip, right? The comparison is not exact, but the principle is the same for radar and sonar.

There are many aspects that would characterize a radar system, I'd say that for the purpose of your question the receiver and frequency in this case might answer it for you.

The frequency of the sent signal does indeed reflect differently for differently sized objects, and this is why we can't observe some objects with radars. If they're small enough their radar cross section is below what the receiver would require or they are simply too transparent at the frequency we're operating at.

The receiver puts other limitations on the systems, with, as you've mentioned in your post, the lowest distinguishable power. The noise floor in a receiver is highly dependent on the type of amplifiers used and the antenna. Narrow beams pick up less RFI for example. With a lower noise floor, weaker signals can be detected, which means that for a fixed range, objects with a smaller radar cross section may be observed. Keep in mind however, that radar cross section is not the same as physical cross section, but is the term used when dealing with radars.

Comment: Not a scientific explaination, you have to agree :)

Comment: We are not drawing anything, we are recieving a reflected pulse, and even within a wavelength, different parts of a wave have different phases and thus are distinguishable.

Comment: I do agree, but i believe the comparison still makes a point. @shah.shah You don't have to explain to me how a radar works, I am very well aware with my degree, thank you. Due to the way the question was asked I don't believe throwing equations in his/her face will ease learning.

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude at all, sorry if you were offended. I was just explaining why I didn't think this was a good analogy

Comment: @shah.shah We've a difference of opinion then, i believe it gets the point through. I've updated my answer nonetheless, let's hope it answers his/hers question

Comment: @shah.shah Oh , sorry i didn't notice. I'll be less defensive then haha do you still have questions, can i explain something further to you? I've my degree in microwave and photonics systems so ask ahead,

Comment: Thanks. From what I've understood, a wave is reflected off an object at different depths (up to one wavelength) and all those sum up to give us the final reflected wave (because they all have the same phase), so if the object isn't deep enough (less than a wavelength), the reflection won't be 'complete', right? Not enough amplitude plus background noise would mean we can't measure the distance effectively. Is this correct?

Comment: That is one way to look at it, and it is not incorrect. You're right. It is a question of absorbing and re-radiating the field, and smaller objects don't absorb as much, and as a result of this don't re-radiate as much either. Not enough amplitude and background noise means we cant measure distance at all (if the amplitude is below the noise floor), if the amplitude is above the noise floor, we can detect it with the same accuracy. The noise floor basically sets the limit. Eiter we can see it or we can not.